# Minimum Description Length (MDL) to Correlate Nominal Features

Tags: feature-selection

Currently, I am reviewing this document: [https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~mhall/thesis.pdf](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/%7Emhall/thesis.pdf). In section 4.2.3 it describes an MDL measure of attribute quality to correlate two nominal features. Nevertheless, I haven't managed to understand the computation of MDL.

Are there any implementations in Python? Are there any alternatives?